# What calculation to show what is really "statistical significant" result that justify the choice of one system over another?

Tags: statistical-significance

Sorry for the a bit vague question. Here is the situation why I want to know the answer.

I have developed a system and it is compared to an existing system.

The samples are sentences from documents. Of course, sentences taken from the same documents show the same trend. So they are not completely independent of each other.

37 documents are chosen (by my boss) to test the two systems.

My system reports better true +ve/ true -ve value(for example, 50 true +ve vs 49 true +ve) for sentences from most of the smaller files but there are two big files which I lose big. (doc 15 and doc 24).  The two big files are admitted to be "exceptional" case by my boss. But he seems to be blinded by the total true +ve, true -ve reported over all the sentences taken from the 37 documents and speak of the total result as "statistical significant" and it is everything.

The large variance of the true +ve, true -ve number between documents immediately makes me feel that the claim of statistical significance does not feel right. But how can I show this to my boss.

This is the link to the data I create.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Wmvc-VtvzSd_mnXr_c51v_Ob35gpwaUk

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

---

Response to questions:

Q: you have system A and B, each is repeated many times in different docs?

A: Correct

Q: So what is the question now?

A: As you can see, using the overall accuracy based on the total number of TP+TN  to measure performance, one would say system B is better. And my boss speaks of this being statistical significant. I am sure he is wrong because significance test calculation is based on variance. And these files show large variance. How can I apply any test to show that this result is not statistical significant?

Q: Why are some docs colored red?

A: The red lines are the documents that have the largest variance.

Comment: What is `true +ve/ true -ve`? What is your system? What is the model used? How does this model use sentences to perform statistics?

Comment: Welcome to cross validated! In addition to @user2974951's questions, we'll need false positives and false negatives in addition to true positives and true negatives (maybe best in a table).

Comment: Hi, user2974951 and cbeleites, thanks for your comment. I have edited my post and put a link to my data. Please feel free to comment. Thanks in advance.

Comment: OK, so you have system A and B, each is repeated many times in different docs? For each doc you applied some sort of classification algorithm and got a confusion matrix, and from this the TN, TP,... So what is the question now? Why are some docs colored red?

Comment: Thanks a lot. User2974951. I edit my post to answer your questions. Thanks in advance for any input.